# Intersecting Integral points $(x,y,z)$ of $3x+5y+4z=45$ and $z^2+xy=15$?

Tags: diophantine-equations

I am trying to find all the intersecting integral points $(x,y,z)$ of the plane $$3x+5y+4z=45$$ and the one-sheeted paraboloid $$z^2+xz=15$$.

I noticed that 
$$x=4t-(9-y)$$
$$z=-3t+2(9-y)$$
So I replaced $x,z$. I ended up with the hyperbola $$9 t^2 + 16 t y - 108 t + 5 y^2 - 81 y + 309 = 0$$
which I solved to find infinitely many integral solutions including $$(2,7,1)$$.
My question is: Is there any easier method to find all those points knowing a common intersecting integral point?

Comment: The equation of hyperbola you got, put it in standard form and then you can find all rational (integral) solutions by using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Parametric_equations) parametrization of hyperbola.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I’ll try it.